# Including a perl file that is generated in current file

Tags: perl, include

I am working on a perl script that successfully generates output files containing hashes. I want to use those hashes in my file. Is it possible to include a file that is generated in that file or will I have to create another file?

Technically, it might be cleaner to start a new .pl file that uses those hashes, but I would like to keep everything in a single script if possible. Is it even possible to do so?

Edit:  I'm just unsure if I can "circle" it back around so I can use those hashes in my file because the hashes are generated on a weekly basis. I don't want my file to mistakenly reach out for last week's hashes instead of the newly generated ones. I have not yet wrote my script in a manner to classify each week's generated hashes.

In summary, here is what my file does. It extracts a table from another file. removes columns and rows that are not needed. Once left with the only two columns needed, it takes them and puts them into a hash. One column being the key and the other being the value. For this reason, I've found Data::Dumper to be the best option for my hashes. I'm intermediate in Perl and this is a script I'm putting together for an internship.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197069/discussion-on-question-by-sfr-including-a-perl-file-that-is-generated-in-current).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can save a hash as JSON to a file and later read back the JSON to a perl hash. This example is using [`JSON::XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON::XS;

{
    my %h = (a => 1, b => 2);
    my $str = encode_json( \%h );
    my $fn = 'test.json';
    save_json( $fn, \%h );
    my $h2 = read_json( $fn );
    print Dumper( $h2 );
}


sub read_json {
    my ( $fn ) = @_;

    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    my $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
    close $fh;
    my $h = decode_json $str;
    return $h;
}

sub save_json {
    my ( $fn, $hash ) = @_;

    my $str = encode_json( $hash );
    open ( my $fh, '>', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    print $fh $str;
    close $fh;
}
```

**Output**:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 1,
          'b' => 2
        };
```

Some alternatives to JSON are [YAML](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML) and [Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable).

Comment: Thank you for this! I was getting an error while trying to use JSON. The way that I am getting my data for the hash is by pushing into an array and then using decode_json(\%that_variable); I don't actually manually type the data that goes on. The data generated for the array I'm using to make the hash is coming from some automated scripts. I get the error saying "malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "HASH(0x884248)")".

Comment: I seems like the JSON file is not correct. Can you check if it looks ok? If the JSON file is malformed, it is likely a problem with how you pass the data to `encode_json` before you write the file

Comment: I just fixed some mistakes I had and it is now working. i guess this brings me to my question: I am running the main portion of the code that calls the sub in a foreach loop. I need a hash generated for 4 files. I still don't understand how I can access those hashes as variables in my script.

Comment: It is difficult to know what to recommend without seeing the code. Maybe you could send me the code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to due to my company privacy policy but I'll try to do some extra research on the matter. Thank you for helping me get the output using JSON though!

Comment: @sfr, `decode_json(\%that_variable)` makes no sense. It should be `decode_json($json)`

Comment: @ikegami I got it to work eventually. Just worked off of his example.